# Instagram scoops a lot of data on my phone

Tags: windows-10-mobile, instagram

I have Instagram App for Windows Mobile 10 installed on my Lumia 640 XL Dual SIM.

Beside the crashes due to the RAM hunger of this App (e.g it crashes whe I try to upload videos), I have another problem: Instagram loads a lot of data on my phone. The installation itself has 94 MB but within a few days the App stored more then 500 MB of data on my phone. I have to reset the app every week (this option aling with memory usage can be found in the Storage settings of the phone).

This is annoying because my plan (the contract with the mobile service provider) includes currently just 7GB traffic monthly and Instagram consumes a lot of that. 
Other than that, I have no micro SD currently in my phone because the last one got corrupted again (second one within a here, see here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174277/can-i-make-my-micro-sd-card-physically-unreadable-if-i-cut-the-card-including-i) so I have only internal memory available.

My question: Where can I configure that instagram does not load any data on m phone anymore (except my password credentials)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the question completely, but if you are asking "How do I limit the background processes of the apps?" You have two options:

1) Go to **Network & Wireless>>Data Usage>>Restrict background data** This will restrict apps running and using your data when you are using data only.

2) Go to **Privacy>>Background apps>>Instagram** you can un-check instagram on the list. You will no longer run instagram in the background.

If you are wondering "How do I limit my apps storage space?" then I dont have an answer for you. Good luck!

Comment: "How do I limit my apps storage space?" was actually my question but I mark your reply as the accepted answer nevertheless since it helped to minimize the traffic a bit after all. :-)